# Need to set scheduled_delivery_time and validityperiod as NULL in smpp in Kannel

Tags: configuration, smpp, kannel

I have to set scheduled_delivery_time and validityperiod in one of my SMPP to null. I tried few of the following options in smpp-configuration file, but getting error from kannel that SMPP cannot be added.

```
schedule_delivery_time = 0
validityperiod = 1
```

and

```
schedule_delivery_time = NULL
validityperiod = NULL
```

And I also tried `validityperiod` and `validity_period`,but neither worked.

I couldn't find any proper documentation for this.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?